# Longitudinal correlation structure for messy data set?

Tags: dataset, autocorrelation

My data set tracks a bunch of animals throughout a period of a couple of months.

But, it's a messy data set. It's not like I have responses from week 1, week 2, week 3, week 4, and so on.

Instead, I have responses from random dates. Some animals have a response every day during these months.

Others, have a response here and there.

So, how do I model the correlation structure of such a data set? What I mean is, I can include random effects from each animal, but what about how that changes over time?

Answer (score 1):

I would fit a multilevel model. You would have to put your data in long format, with each time being whenever the person responded.

$Response_{it} = \gamma_{00} + \beta_1Time + u_{0i} + e_{it}$

Where:

$\gamma_{00}$ is the average intercept across subjects

$\beta_1$ is the fixed effect of time

$u_{0i}$ is how much a subject deviates from the average intercept

$e_{it}$ is the residual term

The R code in `lme4` would look something like:

`response ~ 1 + time + (1|animal)`

Observations would be nested within animal. Multilevel models allow some people to have 3 measurement occasions, others 10. Some can have times at 7, 10, 13, and 21 days, another animal could have times at 10, 30, and 50 days.